# How to connect to database from custom files/classes in Silex

Tags: php, doctrine, silex

I'm trying this mini framework for the first time and this is my first time at all using justa a framework:)
I added the doctrine service to my index.php file like this:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'db.options' => array(
        'driver'   => 'pdo_sqlite',
        'path'     => __DIR__.'/../include/database.sqlite',
    ),
));
```

and I create a new file with a class with a static method that resturn an array, for example.

```
<?php

namespace MyNameSpace;


class myClass{

    static function getStuff(){


       return array(1 => array('foo'=> 'bar',
                               'bar' => 'foo',
                              )
                   );

    }

}
```

As you can see it's hardcoded so I decide to use a database (sqlite is enought) but I don't know how to get access to $app variable inside my file.

On the other way, all the tutorials that I can find online are confusing and referred to a old Silex's version with the .phar file that now is deprecated, and the directory structures of all examples I found are differente from mine (taken from the fat Silex zip file)

The directory structure of my project is this:

```
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── src
│   └── MyNameSpace
│       └── myClass.php
├── vendor
│   └── composer
│   └── doctrine
│   └── silex
│   └── ...
│   └── **autoload.php**
└── web
    └── css
    └── img
    └── js
    └── views
    └── .htaccess
    └── index.php
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing you need to know is that accessing `$app` is a bad practice. You should DI when it is possible. If you really want to do that, check the code below.

Inside `index.php` (usually `bootstrap.php`) declare a new service:

```
$app['my_class'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    // Retrieve the db instance and create an instance of myClass
    return new \MyNameSpace\myClass($app['db']);
});
```

Add a constructor sur `myClass`:

```
namespace MyNameSpace;

class myClass
{
    /**
     * The connection
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
     */
    private $db;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param $db \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
     */
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you can retrieve a fully initialized instance of `myClass` like this:

```
$myClass = $app['my_class'];
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I don't have the boostrap.php file. Everybody is talkin about this file but no one explain where to call it. I edit the first answer with my directory structure, if you can please tell me where to call the bootstrap file, thanks

Comment: **Edit 1:** Now retrieve the db connection instead of `$app`

Comment: **Edit 2:** Renamed `bootstrap.php` to `index.php`

Comment: so in the news version of Silex, the bootsrap is the index.php? and the autoload.php is?

Comment: but I'm not using composer, I download the "fat version" of zip file like described on the site and extract "as is" in my web root. So I dive a try to your question, btw if I can ask here, I don't know how to register my custom namespace:(

Comment: as for the answer. I don't know if it's a bad pratice, I don't know if I'm follow the correct way to do this neither. I need to connect to database and retrieve some data inside my custom files/class, all the example in the documentation refer to this $app variable. Maybe the title of the question is'nt the correct one

Comment: I will not do to much support on this so now the best thing you can do to learn Silex is to look how others do! [This project](https://github.com/lyrixx/Silex-Kitchen-Edition) is a good starting point as it uses most of Silex features and is up-to-date.

Comment: so you don't know the exact way to get db connection in custom files?:(. I'll take a look at the link